# Postgresql - How to get largest value in column under constant

Tags: postgresql

How do I get the largest value in a column under a constant?
Specifically, in a table with a column of speed values how can I get the row with largest speed, under an arbitrary limit (say, 1200 mph)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a list of all the rows that fall below your maximum, then `ORDER BY` speed and `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE speed < 1200
ORDER BY speed DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If no row satisfies your criteria (i.e. the table is empty or every row has a speed larger than 1200), the query will return no rows.  You should be prepared to handle this eventuality.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, this is a simple `max()` with a `where` condition:

```
select max(speed)
from some_table
where speed < 1200;
```

Comment: This approach only returns the speed column, not the whole row.